# Restoring all messages of a thread in Gmail at once

Tags: gmail

Is there any way to restore all messages of a thread in the Gmail web interface at once?

E.g. some messages of a thread have been deleted but not all:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if we are using the same Gmail web version. They propagate versions in batches I noticed. But in my version I can go to Trash and click the thread and just remove the Trash tag.

Comment: This worked for me, delete entire message than move to inbox afterwards